# The direct product $G\times E$ of a group $G$ with a right zero semigroup $E$ is a right group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, semigroups, magma

This is part of Exercise 2.6.6 of Howie's *"Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory"*. I apologise in advance if this is a duplicate.

### The Details:

Let $S$ be a semigroup.

> **Definition 1:** We call $S$ *right simple* if $\mathcal R=S\times S$, where $\mathcal R$ is Green's $R$-relation.
>
> **Definition 2:** We call $S$ *left cancellative* if $(\forall a, b, c\in S) ca=cb\implies a=b$.
>
> **Definition 3:** If $S$ is right simple and left cancellative, then $S$ is by definition a *right group*.
>
> **Definition 4:** If for all $a, z\in S$, $az=z$, then $S$ is a *right zero semigroup*.

### The Question:

> Show that if $G$ is a group and $E$ is a right zero semigroup, then the direct product $G\times E$ is a right group.

### My Attempt:

Let $(g, e), (h, f)\in G\times E$. Then
$$\begin{align}
(g, e)G\times E&=\left\{(gi, d)\mid (i, d)\in G\times E\right\} \\
&=G\times E
\end{align}$$ and similarly $(h, f)G\times E=G\times E$, so $(g, e)\mathcal R (h, f)$. Thus $\mathcal R=S\times S$, so $S$ is right simple.

Suppose $(g, d), (h, e), (i, f)\in G \times E$ such that $$
(i, f)(g, d)=(i, f)(h, e).
$$ Then $ig=ih\implies g=h$ and $d=fd=fe=e$, so $S$ is left cancellative.

Hence $G\times E$ is a right group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.
$\def\x{                                          }$